# Sequence of numbers related to line-segment intersections

Tags: discrete-geometry, integer-sequences

**Question:**

what is known about the sequence $\mathbb{X}\subset \mathbb{N}_0$ such that for each $k\in \mathbb{X}$ there exists a set of $n$ points in general position in the Euclidean plane such that the set of line segments that connect pairs of the points intersect in exactly $k$ inner points?

In general position in this context means that no three are collinear.

I don't want to rule out the case where 3 lines intersect in an point, so I ask to indicate in answers to which case they relate, to stable ones, where the number of intersections doesn't change if the point locations are modified by a sufficiently small distance for all directions, or to the critical on where we have a direciton, in which a point can't be moved without changing the number o intersections, no matter how small the positive distance is.

Comment: Can 3 line segments intersect in one point?

Comment: @MaxAlekseyev I am tempted to allow both variants,meaning that both cases are interesting in their own right.

Comment: It's worth to compute first few terms and check if they are present in https://oeis.org/

Comment: @MaxAlekseyev my guess would be that no solution exists for 2 intersections

Comment: If $n$ points were the vertices of a convex polygon, and no 3 line segments were allowed to intersect at one point, then the answer would be $\binom{n}{4}$.

Comment: @MaxAlekseyev you are right, I was misled by the idea of lines intersecting a diagonal. The correct argument is that every quadruplet of points defines a convex quadrilateral which has exactly one pair of insecting line segments.